# Jquery's conflicting with one another

Tags: jquery, html

I have a JQuery drop down list that is working perfectly until I try add a Jquery datepicker on the same page. The datepicker works but the drop down list is removed. I'm unsure as to what is causing the conflict, I trying to get both of them to work.

----head----

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="fancystyle1/styles.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css"  >

  <script src="fancystyle1/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="fancystyle1/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
         </script>

<script src="fancystyle1/js/jquery.simple.select.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('select').selectBoxes();  
                });             
            </script>

</head>
```

Comment: Avoid using 2 versions of jQuery on your website if you can. jQuery Version 1.11.1 is your best bet for older-browser compatibility. Otherwise just stick with your highest version (1.9.0) and dump the other (1.6.2)

Comment: You should also show your combined page, rather than the two separate pages. Then the advice on what to change will be specific :)

Comment: Answer updated below. Includes styles, then scripts (only 1 jQuery and that before the other scripts), then the page-specific code at the end of the body.

Comment: Just tried your answer but no luck the datepicker doesn't work and it screws with the style a bit..

Comment: Yes, it was missing one of your style files (edited)... please assume that is a guide only *as you did not provide the full page* :)

Comment: if both the jquery scripts are needed then you can use `noConflict()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Might just have to leave out the datepicker :/.. is there another way to create a datepicker with jquery?

Comment: `datepicker` is the way to go... update your jQuery UI to at least 1.9.2: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4yfju34b/

Answer (score 0):

You included jQuery library twice, here:

```
<script src="fancystyle1/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

and here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the reason of conflict. Just remove 2nd string from your code.

Comment: Those code examples shown are two separate pages. The combined result is not shown, so you need to see the final version too before saying "delete the 2nd string" :)

Comment: Removing the second one stops the date picker from working unfortunately though...

Comment: Sorry true blue, should have made it more clear... that code is all on one page.. just tried seperating it to for viewing

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yeah, may be you are right and this is 2 different pages. Need to see resulting merged page.

Comment: @Dan_ENZ, just show us resulting page without any separations. Edit your question listing.

Comment: Ok I have edited it to show everything that is currently in my head. Hopefully this is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using 2 versions of jQuery on your website if you can. jQuery Version 1.11.1 is your best bet for older-browser compatibility. Otherwise just stick with your highest version (1.9.0) and dump the other (1.6.2)

Elements are missing from your example (e.g. the select), but you will want something like this now:

```
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="fancystyle1/styles.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css"  >      
  <script src="fancystyle1/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="fancystyle1/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="fancystyle1/js/jquery.simple.select.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="datepicker" style="width: 100px;"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('select').selectBoxes();  
       $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });             
    </script>
</body>
```

**Notes:**

- Include your scripts in the head element (at least for now so you can find them easily). Efficiency/caching/bundling changes come later.
- Include jQuery before jQuery UI and before any other scripts that use jQuery.
- Only include 1 version of jQuery *if you can*. Supporting multiple simultaneous versions is a nightmare.
- Query 1.11.1 is the current best/latest version for older browser support.
- The page-specific jQuery is wrapped in a DOM ready event handler so can go anywhere in the page. At the end of `body` is a common position, but in the `head` is also fine.